# Debug arduino code

Tags: debugging, arduino, frequency, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am making a project to get the wind speed from an anemometer.
I use an Arduino with a Base Shield and my anemometer (08492 on sparkfun)
I already did a code but it did not work, I have some errors that I can't understand, if someone can help me to debug it it will be very cool :D

```
long mesure_frequence;
int anemo = 4;
unsigned long periode = 0;
unsigned long etat_bas = 0;
unsigned long etat_haut = 0;
unsigned long freq = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(anemo, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char tempo_minutes=10;
    unsigned long frequence;
    float vitesse_vent[3];
    float vitesse_moyenne;

    for(i=0; i>2; i++) /*boucle for pour récuperer 3 valeur*/
    {
        frequence=mesure_frequence;
        vitesse_vent[i]=frequence*1.492; //1Hz = 1,492KMh
        vitesse_moyenne=(vitesse_vent[0]+vitesse_vent[1]+vitesse_vent[2])/3;
    }

    /*envoyer en i2c*/
    for(i=1; i>tempo_minutes; i++)
    { 
        delay(60000);
    } 

    {
    Serial.print (vitesse_moyenne);
    }
}

int unsigned long mesure_frequence(void);

    unsigned long periode = 0;
    unsigned long etat_bas = 0;
    unsigned long etat_haut = 0;
    unsigned long freq = 0;

    etat_bas = pulseIn(anemo, LOW); //mesure de l'état bas du signal en microsecondes
    if (etat_bas==0)
    {
        etat_haut=0;
    }
    else
    {
        etat_haut = pulseIn(anemo, HIGH);  //mesure de l'état haut du signal en microsecondes
    }

    periode=etat_bas+etat_haut;  //calcul de la période du signal en microsecondes
    if (periode==0)
    {
        freq=0;
    }
    else
    {
        freq=1000000/periode;  //calcul de la fréquence du signal en secondes
    }
```

---

Finally, i have a biggest problem, in the datashett it says that i can convert 1 pulse to 1.492MPH but it false, it is 2 pulse for 1.492MPH so i may use something else than PulseIn, maybe FreqMeasure or AttachInterrupt, can someone help me pls !

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: actually that : 'long unsigned int mesure_frequence()' redeclared as different kind of symbol

Comment: do you know where the problem is from?

Answer (score 1):

- The conditions used in `for` loops are not correct.
- You shouldn't use uninitialized non-static local variables.
- You may want to *call* the functon mesure_frequence` instead of *getting the pointer* to the function.
- The first line of definition of `mesure_frequence` is wrong:

  - The return type `int unsigned long` is invalid.
  - The implemetation of function have to be between `{` and `}`.
- You declared a variable `mesure_frequence` and then defined a function having same name, which is illegal.
- The function `mesure_frequence` must return some value.

Possible fix:

```
int anemo = 4;
unsigned long periode = 0;
unsigned long etat_bas = 0;
unsigned long etat_haut = 0;
unsigned long freq = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(anemo, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char tempo_minutes=10;
    unsigned long frequence;
    float vitesse_vent[3];
    float vitesse_moyenne;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) /*boucle for pour récuperer 3 valeur*/
    {
        frequence=mesure_frequence();
        vitesse_vent[i]=frequence*1.492; //1Hz = 1,492KMh
    }
    vitesse_moyenne=(vitesse_vent[0]+vitesse_vent[1]+vitesse_vent[2])/3;

    /*envoyer en i2c*/
    for(i=0; i<tempo_minutes; i++)
    { 
        delay(60000);
    } 

    {
    Serial.print (vitesse_moyenne);
    }
}

unsigned long mesure_frequence(void) {

    unsigned long periode = 0;
    unsigned long etat_bas = 0;
    unsigned long etat_haut = 0;
    unsigned long freq = 0;

    etat_bas = pulseIn(anemo, LOW); //mesure de l'état bas du signal en microsecondes
    if (etat_bas==0)
    {
        etat_haut=0;
    }
    else
    {
        etat_haut = pulseIn(anemo, HIGH);  //mesure de l'état haut du signal en microsecondes
    }

    periode=etat_bas+etat_haut;  //calcul de la période du signal en microsecondes
    if (periode==0)
    {
        freq=0;
    }
    else
    {
        freq=1000000/periode;  //calcul de la fréquence du signal en secondes
    }
    return freq;
}
```

Comment: Ok thank's i understood what you means but i still don't understeand about the function, what is wrong in? why it makes the same error ?

Comment: @AnisBouAllegue Sorry for overlooking. Updated.

Comment: @AnisBouAllegue What is wrong is written in the error message.